# outliers in regression, selection of a specific region of the samples

Tags: regression, outliers, robust

I have a set of points/samples like the ones in blue in the image below: there is a bunch of wiggly nonsense here and there, and somewhere in the middle the is a region of almost perfect linear fit (red line). I want to find the coefficient of that red line. But at the moment I'm stuck with different variations the green line. Even for outlier robust methods, like RANSAC.

I know that it's a lot of outliers, but give than most outliers and inliers cluster together - lie in the same region of the space - is there no way to harness that?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you restrict your regression to the interval you are interested in?

Comment: Outliers are a minority of the data that behaves differently from the majority. There can't be more than half of the data that is outliers. From what I see, more than half of your data is outlier so it is not really a robust problem. Maybe you could use multiple regressions, i.e. something like this : https://towardsdatascience.com/locally-weighted-linear-regression-in-python-3d324108efbf